# Common mocks defined with @patch to several test case functions in Python

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-mock

I have this testing code in Python using mocks (simplified):

```
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import patch

class TestClass(TestCase):

    @patch("mymodule.function1")
    @patch("mymodule.function2")
    @patch("mymodule.function3")
    def test_case_1(self, function3_mock, function2_mock, function1_mock):
       # code for test_case_1
       ...

    @patch("mymodule.function1")
    @patch("mymodule.function2")
    @patch("mymodule.function3")
    def test_case_2(self, function3_mock, function2_mock, function1_mock):
       # code for test_case_2
       ...

    @patch("mymodule.function1")
    @patch("mymodule.function2")
    @patch("mymodule.function3")
    def test_case_3(self, function3_mock, function2_mock, function1_mock):
       # code for test_case_3
       ...

    ...
```

I wonder if there is some way of simplifying this, so:

- I don't repeat all the time the three `@patch(...)` statements in each test case function
- I don't need to pass the mock function to the test case function, so I can call write just `def test_case_1(self)` for instance

Is that possible? Could you provide some hints/advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) you could use `@patch` to decorate the class rather than individual functions? (2) you could use the syntax like `@patch("mymodule.function1", lambda x: 42)`. When you have that second arg specifying what target the patched function is being patched to, the test case function no longer gets an extra arg corresponding to the patch. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch and particularly the special behaviour when *new* is omitted - which is the behaviour you're currently seeing and want to avoid.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have taken advice (1), I have realized that documentation says "Patch can be used as a TestCase class decorator. It works by decorating each test method in the class. This reduces the boilerplate code when your test methods share a common patchings set" so moving all the @patch(...) at class level simplifies the code. Now working in (2)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactored this way achieves both objectives:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import patch, Mock

function1_mock = Mock()
function2_mock = Mock()
function3_mock = Mock()

@patch("mymodule.function1", function1_mock)
@patch("mymodule.function2", function2_mock)
@patch("mymodule.function3", function3_mock)
class TestClass(TestCase):

    def test_case_1(self):
       # code for test_case_1
       ...

    def test_case_2(self):
       # code for test_case_2
       ...

    def test_case_3(self):
       # code for test_case_3
       ...

    ...
```